# how to find the unique non nan values in a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, nan

I would like to know if there is a clean way to handle nan in numpy.

```
my_array1=np.array([5,4,2,2,4,np.nan,np.nan,6])
print my_array1
#[  5.   4.   2.   2.   4.  nan  nan   6.]
print set(my_array1)
#set([nan, nan, 2.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0])
```

I would have thought it should return at most 1 nan value. Why does it return multiple nan values?
I would like to know how many unique non nan values I have in a numpy array.

Thanks

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use `np.unique` to find unique values in combination with `isnan` to filter the `NaN` values:

```
In [22]:

my_array1=np.array([5,4,2,2,4,np.nan,np.nan,6])
np.unique(my_array1[~np.isnan(my_array1)])
Out[22]:
array([ 2.,  4.,  5.,  6.])
```

as to why you get multiple `NaN` values it's because `NaN` values cannot be compared normally:

```
In [23]:

np.nan == np.nan
Out[23]:
False
```

so you have to use `isnan` to perform the correct comparison

using `set`:

```
In [24]:

set(my_array1[~np.isnan(my_array1)])
Out[24]:
{2.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0}
```

You can call `len` on any of the above to get a size:

```
In [26]:

len(np.unique(my_array1[~np.isnan(my_array1)]))
Out[26]:
4
```

Comment: As of Numpy version 1.21.0, *np.unique now returns single NaN*.

Answer (score 9):

I'd suggest using pandas. I think it's a direct replacement, but pandas keeps the original order unlike numpy.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

my_array1=np.array([5,4,2,2,4,np.nan,np.nan,6])

np.unique(my_array1)
# array([ 2.,  4.,  5.,  6., nan, nan])

pd.unique(my_array1)
# array([ 5.,  4.,  2., nan,  6.])
```

I'm using numpy 1.17.4 and pandas 0.25.3. Hope this helps!

Comment: That still gives you NaNs, so what's the point?

Comment: Thanks for the question. It removes duplicates, and leaves only a single nan, which is useful for determining the number of unique values. Just an alternative approach. Also good in getting the unique values without loosing the order. As per the question "at most 1 nan value"

Answer (score 2):

As previous answers have already stated, numpy can't count nans directly, because it can't compare nans. `numpy.ma.count_masked` is your friend. For example, like this:

```
>>> import numpy.ma as ma
>>> a = np.array([ 0.,  1., np.nan, np.nan,  4.])
>>> a
np.array([ 0.,  1., nan, nan,  4.])
>>> a_masked = ma.masked_invalid(a)
>>> a_masked
masked_array(data=[0.0, 1.0, --, --, 4.0],
             mask=[False, False,  True,  True, False],
       fill_value=1e+20)
>>> ma.count_masked(a_masked)
2
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Numpy version 1.21.0, [np.unique now returns single NaN](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/release/1.21.0-notes.html#np-unique-now-returns-single-nan):

```
>>> a = np.array([8, 1, np.nan, 3, np.inf, np.nan, -np.inf, -2, np.nan, 3])
>>> np.unique(a)
array([-inf,  -2.,   1.,   3.,   8.,  inf,  nan])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [isnan()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html#numpy-isnan) with your setm then iterate through result of isnan() array and remove all NaN objects.

```
my_array1=np.array([5,4,2,2,4,np.nan,np.nan,6])
print my_array1
#[  5.   4.   2.   2.   4.  nan  nan   6.]
print set(my_array1)
#set([nan, nan, 2.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0])
for i,is_nan in enumerate(np.isnan(list(my_array1))):
    if is_nan:
        del my_array1[i]
```

Comment: if you want to remove all NaN elements from an array a MUCH better way is to do:
my_array1 = my_array1[~np.isnan(my_array1)]
It it will operate in a vectorized way (most likely using optimized code) and not iterate at python level.
Not only that it's less code to write, it's also much faster for big arrays.